# Code does not compile with .Net 5.0 (but does with 6.0)

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I am learning Functional Programming in C#. I am following examples and have a definition for  Partition (shown below) which does not compile using .Net 5.0.  It Does WORK with 6.0.
I am having issue spotting the error and wondered if any one could assist.

```
public static (IEnumerable<T> Passed, IEnumerable<T> Failed) Partition<T>
    (
       this IEnumerable<T> source,
       Func<T, bool> predicate
    )
    {
        var grouped = source.GroupBy(predicate);
        return
        (
           Passed: grouped.Where(g => g.Key).FirstOrDefault(Enumerable.Empty<T>()), //(ERROR)
           Failed: grouped.Where(g => !g.Key).FirstOrDefault(Enumerable.Empty<T>())  //(ERROR)
        );
    }
```

The error is

> CS1503    Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Func<System.Linq.IGrouping<bool, T>, bool>'

How do I change this to work in .Net 5.0?

TIA

Comment: the reason it fails is becuase the ability to specify the default to return was added in .net 6. Its not entirely clear to me what you are doing so I am not quite sure of the solution. I mean doesnt the group by bool predicate already partition?

Comment: As to what I am doing - really nothing more than following the book and examples. Of all the code this is the only function that really has to be changed but I am not as familiar with LINQ/Functional operations to know how to fix this. This is a generic function in a library. I don't have much more to go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
        Passed: grouped.Where(g => g.Key).FirstOrDefault()??Enumerable.Empty<T>(), //(ERROR)
        Failed: grouped.Where(g => !g.Key).FirstOrDefault()??Enumerable.Empty<T>()  //(ERROR)
```

`FirstOrDefault` will return null if no entries, the `??` says 'if lhs is null then use the rhs'

Comment: Additionally, and likely why the original error was quite confusing, `FirstOrDefault` has [an overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-5.0#system-linq-enumerable-firstordefault-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-boolean)))) that accepts a `Func<TSource,bool>` as a predicate. This is what the compiler was attempting to call. You could take advantage of that to simplify the code further: `Passed: grouped.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key) ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()` etc.